# Jsoup: Sorting group of elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to display a list of 50 items, each item containing a group of 4 Elements: Title, Price, Location and Date.

```
try {   
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Chrome").timeout(5000).get();

    Elements titles = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    Elements prices = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    Elements locations = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    Elements dates = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    //Elements itemUrls = doc.select("myCssQuery");

    for(int i = 0; i < titles.size()-1; i++) {
       System.out.println(titles.get(i).text());
       System.out.println(prices.get(i).text());
       System.out.println(locations.get(i).text());
       System.out.println(dates.get(i).text());
       System.out.println();
       //System.out.println(itemUrls.get(i).attr("abs:href"));
   }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I have to sort the list by price (currently string but can be converted to int). But the only way I know to get this done is using a database, which I am not willing to do in this case. Is there any way to achieve this without using database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), I have an short implement for you, this is sort by ascending price, you can change `compareTo()` for another way to sort list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Chrome").timeout(5000).get();

    Elements titles = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    Elements prices = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    Elements locations = doc.select("myCssQuery");
    Elements dates = doc.select("myCssQuery");

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Item item;
    for(int i = 0; i < titles.size()-1; i++) {
        item = new Item(titles.get(i).text(), Integer.parseInt(prices.get(i).text().replaceAll("\\D+","")), locations.get(i).text(), dates.get(i).text());    
        items.add(item);
    }

    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
            return item1.compareTo(item2);
        }
    });

}

public static class Item implements Comparable {
    private String title;
    private int price;
    private String location;
    private String date;

       public Item(String title, int price, String location, String date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.location = location;
        this.date = date;
       }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Item item = (Item) o;
        if (this.price == item.price) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.price > item.price) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can implement sort into compare() do not need to implement Comparable in class Item like this:

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
        if (item1.getPrice() == item2.getPrice()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (item1.getPrice() > item2.getPrice()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I was unable to respond for last 2 days 'cause I didn't know much about the Collection Framework, especially the Comparator and Comparable interfaces. I had to study a little to understand your answer. It's working now. Thanks :) And you forgot the constructor. Thanks again :)